# Why is no data sent when I try to save a file from angular to node

Tags: node.js, angular

I am working on a project using an angular 10 frontend and a backend with node and express

I am looking to allow the user to save files.

Back:
Routing :

```
const  multipart  =  require('connect-multiparty');
const  multipartMiddleware  =  multipart({ uploadDir:  './uploads' });

router.post('/image', multipartMiddleware, userCtrl.image)
```

user Ctrl:

```
exports.image = (req,res,next)=>{
    console.log(req.body, req.files);
    res.status(200).json("image enregistrée")
}
```

The back seems to work well as I can save my images from postman

Front:

```
onFileSelected(event){
    this.selectedFiles = event.target.files
  }

  onUpload(){
    let url = environment.back.auth+"/image"
    let formData = new FormData();
    for (var i = 0; i < this.selectedFiles.length; i++) {
        formData.append("uploads[]", this.selectedFiles[i], this.selectedFiles[i].name);
    }
    console.info(formData)
    this.httpClient.post(url, formData ).subscribe(res=> console.info(res))
  }
```

Every time I try to upload an image from angular, the console.log(req.body, req.files) displays {} {} and doesn't log anything
From postman there is no problem, it displays my file and saves it

Do I proceed correctly for the sending of my file? If so, do you have any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: you need to set the form data object as your post body. and set your headers correctly for the content type

Answer (score 0):

you're creating a `FormData` but never using it, gotta actually use it.

```
  onUpload(){
    let url = environment.back.auth+"/image"
    let formData = new FormData();
    for (var i = 0; i < this.selectedFiles.length; i++) {
        formData.append("uploads[]", this.selectedFiles[i], this.selectedFiles[i].name);
    }
    console.info(formData)
    this.httpClient.post(url, formData).subscribe(res=> console.info(res))
  }
```

depending on your backend, might need to set some headers as well.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
It was I wanted to test by sending the file directly and I forgot to edit. Sorry about that 
If I use the formdata directly, the back reacts in the same way. 

Looking at the header of my request there is well: 
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=???

I also tried adding it myself but it doesn't change anything